# Need Workaround for Outlook 2007 HTML Email Rendering Bug (Horizontal Gaps)

Tags: email, rendering, outlook-2007

My HTML email newsletter design doesn't render properly in Outlook 2007. There is a white horizontal gap towards the bottom which breaks borders and backgrounds. I've had this happen before and have no idea how to work around it. Any suggestions? I've posted the source [here](http://websighted.com/stackoverflow.html). It renders just fine except in Outlook 2007 (Word 2007).

By the way, you can preview the problem without Outlook, by opening the source with Word 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that these bugs are related to the size/length of the email and can't be eliminated, though sometimes the effect can be mitigated by editing the content to add additional horizontal spacing or by increasing the line-height attribute of some of the text that precedes the breaks.

Comment: They are related to the length of the email, in that the problem occurs wherever the email finishes a sheet of A4 if you were printing it.

Answer (score 8):

I can't see the original source, but the workaround is to insert a 100% width table somewhere in the design just above where it's breaking. This can be a 1px high transparent line. This allows Outlook to insert a page break.

Outlook is using Word 2007's rendering engine, so if it reaches the end of a sheet of A4 in printing size, it has to insert a page break somewhere. If there's an image in the place where it would otherwise insert that page break, it will just force that image down to the next page - that's the space you are seeing.

Using the 100% table allows Outlook to insert the page break there instead.

Comment: very interesting!  I'm not sure this workaround will work for me though, because my design is (in simplified form) an outer table enclosing two side-by-side tables used as left and right columns.  So, something like this:

Comment: You can make it _look_ the same but it will take some time. I spent ages looking for workarounds on this bug, and designing in such a way that you can have regular 100% tables was the only fix I found.

Comment: @jalperin Did you find a way around the problem? If there's anything else I can help with, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Blowski I'm curious about the rationale of the 100% table widths. We currently have a nested table with a fixed width of 300 within a td of width 300. The content is splitting in the middle of the table, so if I read your solution correctly making the table 100% will cause the entire table to bump down rather than splitting. Is this right?

Comment: @Steve It sounds bizarre, but even when displaying on the screen (and not in print preview) Outlook 2007/2010 is trying to render it to fit on A4. When it reaches a new 'sheet', it will insert a page break. It won't split an image in half, but will instead break the table containing the image. The 100% table thing is a rather brute-force method - you can get around it by moving the image up or down in the design, or even by splitting the image at just the right place, but that can be a lot more work.

Comment: I would upvote this 10000000 times!! This post brought me with my outlook 07 problem on the right path. My issue was that one (1) Table was higher than 23.7 inches...

Comment: As a note, this workaround doesn't seem to work when your design is encapsulated within a table.  When I re-wrote my design to not include the containing table, this worked a charm.  Thank you so much! :)

Comment: This solution will only work if your email is a single column design, as there isn't really a way to make side-by-side columns without involving floats (no Outlook support) or nesting content within table td elements (whose individual elements will accumulate in height and cause the containing td and table to over the page-break threshold). Correct?

Comment: It depends how you design the multicolumn layout. You can have multiple rows: one with two columns, then a 100% row, then another two-column row. It's possible even without doing this, but very awkward - you have to establish where the break is, and slice the email manually at that point.

Comment: I understand what your proposing. That would indeed "look" like a 2-column setup, without actually being a continuous containing table/cell. Unfortunately for me it's not feasible since our email template is populated automatically with content from our website. Thank you though - clever idea!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good explaination of what can cause that bug and how you may be able to fix it:
http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom uses Word to render HTML?  So I let Microsoft write the HTML for me.

- Publish email as a web page
- Copy web page into an Outlook email
- Send the email to yourself
- Get the source code of the email you receive from yourself

That HTML will now work fine.

Don't even bother to decipher the HTML Microsoft creates.  I'll give you a headache.

Next, I had to copy the HTML back into Dreamweaver to fix a few things:

- img src= was all screwed up
- background color you can fix in the Outlook email you send, or in the HTML

By the way, I found if I tried at put the image map hyperlinks back in, the problem resurfaced.  So I just linked the whole image.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have exactly the same problem, as far as i'm aware this is something to do with
Outlook 2007 using Word 2007 as a rendering engine. Because of this, Outlook 2007 puts (what are effectively) page breaks throughout your email (at certain intervals).

I may be completely wrong, but this is how I see it...

Any answers would be rather good!

Comment: Yes, I've experienced this as well, Outlook seems to be adding page breaks to avoid chopping an image in half. Which of course is a silly thing to do for an e-mail unless you're trying to print.

Comment: It's because of the Word rendering engine - it thinks it's still in Word... Silly Microsoft...again...

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that this white line break normally occurs when there is an image close to the line breaks that outlook 2007 inserts. The quick workaround is to insert some text beneath the image so that instead of letting outlook 2007 insert the page break, the extra text will format the pages without any "help" from outlook 2007 hence the disappearance of the mysterious white line.