# Outlook 2007 Adding lots of space above a large image in an HTML email

Tags: outlook, html-email

We've created an HTML template that is rendering correctly on all email clients except for one issue with Outlook 2007. In the middle of the Email, there is a 600px tall ad. In Outlook that ad has around 350px of undesired space above it. As far as we can tell, Outlook is doing some kind of pagination to avoid breaking the image in two (since it's using the Word rendering engine). If we move the ad down, the problem goes away, but that's not a very good option because the size of the content prior to the ad is going to vary each newsletter.

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Outlook 2007 page break bug.

[See my response here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419388/need-workaround-for-outlook-2007-html-email-rendering-bug-horizontal-gaps/5662156#5662156)